# composer packages.json autoload definition

Tags: php, composer-php, repository, autoload

I use composer libraries in my private project to manage common logic and I used to always install them with a "vcs" repository definition like this:

```
"require": {
    "private/package": "dev-develop",
},
"repositories": {
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://localhost/git/private-package.git"
    }
}
```

... which used to work like a charm but was tedious for project where I would use many libraries at once.
So I decided to write my own "composer" type repository that dynamically generates a "packages.json" with all my libraries that looks something like this:

```
"packages" {
    "private/package": {
        "dev-develop": {
            "name": "private/package",
            "version": "dev-develop",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "http://localhost/git/private-package.git",
                "reference": "origin/develop"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The installation works fine but it does not generate the autoloader properly anymore. The installation does not read the "composer.json" file of the actual vcs repository anymore.

The autoloader only works properly if I include the autoloader definition in the "packages.json" file.

I want composer to use the "packages.json" definition, but still read the autoloader definition from the actual package. My question is if that is possible.

If the autoloader definition changes with a newer version of the library, the definition in "packages.json" will not work with an older version anymore so I am thinking there should be another way to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool like Satis?

Comment: It's more that I don't need the entire functionality of Satis for my simple purposes, but Satis could do what I want I think.